# Confused about using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

First of all I should say this is my first jquery application. I am following video tuturials on the internet and trying the same thing. This applicaiton basically checks usernames from a database and lets the user know if this username is available or not and shows a message. First I followed the instructers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001377/best-way-to-add-nuget-packages-as-project-references-in-vs2012) and added jquery 2.1.1. Then I wrote the code just like on the video, typed some value, and nothing happens, neither an exception nor a message. I have 3 week programming backround and dont know what is wrong.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.intellisense.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function check() {
            var username = $('#txtUsername').val();
            PageMethods.CheckName(username, checkmess);
        }

        function checkmess(message) {
            $('#result').html(message);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <br />
    <input id="txtUsername" name="txtUsername" type="text"  onchange="checkFunction();" />
    <div id="result" name="result"></div>
</form>
```

and this is for aspx.cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

[WebMethod]
public static string CheckName(string name) 
{
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("server=.\\sqlexpress;database=Northwind;User Id=sa; Password=1234");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from User where UserName='"+name+"'",cnn);
    string message = "";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        message = "User Exists";
    }
    else 
    {
        message = "UserName is ok ";
    }

    return message;
}
```

Comment: I am missing a question mark in your question... So what is your question?

Comment: Um... neither of your Javascript functions are ever called. To call a function the syntax is functionName()

Comment: @PatrickHofman , hello sir , dont you think you just disrespected OP !

Comment: @PratikJoshi: No, I don't think so. The question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistaken to call `onchange` function for input as your function name is `check()`.

Change

```
<input id="txtUsername" 
       name="txtUsername" 
       type="text"  
       onchange="checkFunction();"/>
```

to

```
 <input id="txtUsername" 
        name="txtUsername" 
        type="text"  
        onchange="check();"/>
        ^ function name corrected.
```