# NuGet command in VS : can install package but not added to packaged.config & project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am having a problem with a package in a private repository, running install-package "PackageName" just install the package in "packages" folder, but the file packages.config doesn't contain this package, also the project file (*.csproj) is not being updated to have reference to this package.

[image]

Normally, it should have a line saying that "Added package to project successfully", but not in this case.

Could anyone please help? Thank you for any idea.

Comment: Is it a solution level package? Those do not add any reference to the project nor get added into the packages.config file, but instead normally cause a .nuget/packages.config file to be created in the solution directory.

Comment: @MattWard It's project level, I installed other packages on nuget.org and it is still function. There was packages.config file already. Thank you.

Comment: What is inside the lib directory inside the .nupkg file?

Comment: Oh, there is no lib folder inside, all files are in the "root" folder. I use the command "nuget spec" then "nuget pack" to create the package. Maybe it didn't working right in my case.

Comment: Without all files in the root NuGet will treat it as a solution level NuGet package and not install it into a project. You will need to add your files to the .nuspec if you are using `nuget pack YourNuSpec.nuspec`. You could also try `nuget pack YourProject.csproj` instead.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I manage to fix the issue now. By default "nuget spec" does add all dll files in the folder and put to the root folder of package. I use <files> to add expected files, and it work now. Thank you @MattWard.

Comment: @MattWard, you should  copy you comments as the answer. People may not notice  your solution in comments.

Answer (score 0):

**An easier way to add reference to a project directly using NPM is described here** [Best way to add NuGet packages as project references in VS2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001377/best-way-to-add-nuget-packages-as-project-references-in-vs2012)

If that does not help perhaps deleting the package already downloaded and installing it again using the -project switch

```
PM> Install-Package Glimpse -Version 1.0.0 -Project MvcApplication1
```

Installs version 1.0.0 of Glimpse into the project named MvcApplication1

**To Manually update the package.config in case it is not updated already, use**

```
nuget update <packages.config>
```

**Note :** This is a quick work-around. If persistent, this issue must be reported so to be included in Nuget's release notes https://docs.nuget.org/Release-Notes/Known-Issues

Comment: If you look at the screenshot fredho is using the Package Manager Console window and not NuGet.exe from the command line so I do not think the link to the command-line-reference helps here. What you have said about possibly a different project being selected could happen in the Package Manager Console window. Looking at the output from the window seems to indicate the package is not being added to any project since no project is mentioned in the output.

Comment: Fredho seems to have difficulty referencing a nuget package off nuget server. I've tried to point him to a GUI based approach of doing it. Also internally since the NPM GUI uses the nuget command, it is essential to know what it would do to understand what to expect in your solution after you've invoked such a command. for starters, I still am proposing that package management for individual projects is easier done on the GUI than using the package.config file, however when requirements get complex an clear understanding of what's under the hood is absolutely necessary

Comment: I agree using the GUI is easier. NuGet does not use NuGet.exe when using the GUI. There is a shared common library called NuGet.Core.dll which is used by both NuGet.exe and the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. The behaviours can be different. NuGet.exe from the command line for example will not run PowerShell scripts, nor will it modify the project file if you are using install or restore commands. It will only modify the project's references if you use nuget update. From the screenshot fredho is using the PowerShell console and not the command line NuGet.exe.