# Nuget Install-Package successful but no reference added to csproj

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, reference, nuget

I've got a bunch of projects in the same solution, which have project dependencies all correctly set between them (when nedded, obviously). There is one project whose DLL has no dependencies to any other project of the same solution (let's name it `My_First_Dll.dll`). I created Nuget packages for all DLLs successfuly.

Now when I go into package manager console in my test project where I want to add certain references created from the first solution, for example `My_Dependent_Dll`, I type `Install-Package MyNamespace.My_Dependent_Dll`. Nuget says it gets the DLL, and I can see it in the packages folder created on my solution folder, in the packages.config file created in my solution, in the references list of the project and even editing the csproj I can see the reference with hintpath. So everything's fine for `My_Dependent_dll`.

**Problem**: `My_First_Dll.dll`, which is referenced by `My_Dependent_dll`, according to the nuget output, is successfuly installed as well (as it should, bc it is referenced by `My_Dependent_Dll`), and the dll actually is downloaded to the packages folder and added to the packages.config. **BUT** `My_First_Dll` is not added to the references in the solution explorer, and is completly missing from the csproj. So it "doesn't exist" for Visual Studio.

None of the questions here helped me.

Comment: Another reason may be "Without all files in the root NuGet will treat it as a solution level NuGet package and not install it into a project." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801109/nuget-command-in-vs-can-install-package-but-not-added-to-packaged-config-pro?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

Apparently nuget doesn't like dlls ending in `.resources.dll`. And guess what? My non_dependent_DLL had exactly that ending.

Reference:

on https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference

> NuGet does not add references to any dlls that end with '.resources.dll'

which lead me to the explanation in the following link

http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/280566

Hope it helps anyone with this problem.