# How to add nuget server dll into the solution

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I started a new solution all together and this project required to use DLLs that are in nuget server. I was given nuget server path along with user name & pwd.

I have enabled pacakge manager for solution whihc created .nuget folder along with three files.
But, when I selkect pacakge manager from solution and it doest show up any dlls under isntalled pacakges. I need to pull some 5 odd dlls from nuget server. pls help me how to do this to pull the dlls from server and add it to project as a referrences.
?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to add NuGet packages as project references in VS2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001377/best-way-to-add-nuget-packages-as-project-references-in-vs2012)

Comment: This question is already asked and answered here. Please look up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001377/best-way-to-add-nuget-packages-as-project-references-in-vs2012 and see if that helps you.

Comment: I figured out, I had to check under online -> Nuget pacakge official source to find out existing nuget server dlls. all other reffered links showing under "installed pacakges" rather hence had a trouble in identifying the dlls forom nuget server. hope this will help someone.