# How to store data on a single line in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, text

I need to be able to store the data in an array to appear in a list box, so far I can only get the first word (the names) of the text file.

I have been using the Line Split method, though this splits all of the parts into there own line, Doing this method also brings the "Index was outside the bounds of the array." Please help, I have been stuck on this 2 full days now.

```
// - - - - - - - Selection Screen - - - - - - -
public SelectionScreen()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Loading from text file.
    string[] PrimaryArray = new string[12];
    PrimaryArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Test1.txt");

    foreach (string line in PrimaryArray)
    {
        string[] Parts = line.Split(',');

        CharStats temp = new CharStats();
        temp.Name = Parts[0];
        temp.Description = Parts[1];
        temp.Notes = Parts[2];
        temp.MaxHP = Convert.ToInt16(Parts[3]);
        temp.MaxMP = Convert.ToInt32(Parts[4]);
        temp.Atk = Convert.ToInt32(Parts[5]);
        temp.Def = Convert.ToInt32(Parts[6]);
        temp.Mat = Convert.ToInt32(Parts[7]);
        temp.Mdf = Convert.ToInt32(Parts[8]);
        temp.Agi = Convert.ToInt16(Parts[9]);
        temp.Luk = Convert.ToInt16(Parts[10]);
        temp.Lvl = Convert.ToInt16(Parts[11]);

        ListboxCharacterList.Items.Add(temp.Name);
    }
}

// - - - - - - - Writing stats - - - - - - -
public string WriteStats()
{
    return Environment.NewLine + Name + "," + Description + "," + Notes + "," + 
        MaxHP + "," + MaxMP + "," + Atk + "," + Def + "," + Mat + "," + 
        Mdf + "," + Agi + "," + Luk + "," + Lvl;
}

// - - - - - - - TextFile - - - - - - -
//Mike,Desc.,Notes,1000,500,6,7,3,2,6,9
```

Comment: Thanks for that, though this error shows when more "characters" are added to the list. Unfortunately I still get the error is there a more flexible approach to this?

Comment: @mathew Don't use grave accent (\`) in your code when posting on SO. It is used to mark sourcecode. Example \`Test\` will be show this way: `Test`

Comment: @Kara Sorry, my bad

Comment: I would step through with a debugger and inspect the variables to see if they are receiving the values you think they are. Particularly I'd want to know what is in `string[] Parts`. There could be some issue with the way you are saving the file, for example, so debugging the code is only part of it; you also have to ensure the code and file are both "to spec" in precisely the same way.

Comment: In your sample TextFile, you have 11 comma separated values, but your code expects 12 comma separated values. This will undoubtedly cause an IndexOutOfBounds exception, when fetching `Parts[11]`

Comment: `I need to be able to store the data in an array to appear in a list box`. There are many ways of doing it. So to offer a good suggestion, we would need to know the `CharStats` class and how the data from listbox is accessed & utilized

Comment: I will add that, thank you!

Comment: So the list box is going to read to other text boxes on the screen. So here is some pseudo code to explain it.   1) User sames to file (format above.)  2)The file is read to the other screen with the list box. 3)The user clicks the specific name they want to load. 4)The text files information is then used to load into text boxes on the other screen (where the user had customised them.)

Answer (score 0):

A `ListBox` can contain any instance of any `class`. You can Add your `CharStats` to it. You only have to override `ToString()` which is executed to show the values in the box. If you want to select the `SelectedItem`(s) you have to cast it `CharStats`.

A Csv-File can be easily read with `CsvHelper` (`NuGet`-package). Here a exaple:

```
public class CharStats
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
    }
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // From File:
    // FirstName;LastName;Age
    // d;D;4
    // e;E;5
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\myfile.csv"))
    {
        using (CsvHelper.CsvReader csvReader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(sr))
        {
            IEnumerable<CharStats> statList = csvReader.GetRecords(typeof(CharStats)).Cast<CharStats>();

            foreach (CharStats cs in statList)
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(cs);
            }
        }
    }

    this.listBox1.Items.Add(new CharStats() { FirstName = "a", LastName = "A", Age = 1 });
    this.listBox1.Items.Add(new CharStats() { FirstName = "b", LastName = "B", Age = 2 });
    this.listBox1.Items.Add(new CharStats() { FirstName = "c", LastName = "C", Age = 3 });

    this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;

    var item = this.listBox1.SelectedItem;

    CharStats selected = item as CharStats;

    if (selected != null)
        MessageBox.Show("Worked. We selected: " + selected.FirstName + " " +     selected.LastName + " (" + selected.Age + ")");
}
```

This will show a ListBox like this:

> a A
>
> b B
>
> c C

And selected will be the correct object. The `MessageBox` will show

> b B (2)

Comment: Thank you, that works! But how can I read this information form the text file as I need to be able to read from this to first have a user save the details. Thank you again!

Comment: Sorry my Typing is not amazing. But in theory this would work great if I can state the string values to read from a text file

Comment: Post some exaple Data. 2 rows and an explanation. I'll Post some Code for this. (And don't post in comment. Edit your question ;-) )

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you are asking for, I did not sleep last night at all :/ can you elaborate please?

Comment: I need to carry all of the data from one line in the text file to the other page in the application, though this has to be done through the list box as the user will select the person they created as when they make a character, it creates a new line. Sorry for being inconvenient. I really need to complete this task soon though. Should I try and convey what I am going for in the question?

Comment: Sounds like, you got multiple questions. Added a CSV-Reader to my example. But you should post one problem after another. 1. Read `CsvFile`, 2. Handle a `ListBox`.

Comment: Thank you. I will let you know how I get on,

Comment: you're welcome. Fell free to accept or vote up my answer

Comment: Before I carry on, The "Cvs helper" can not be found and I can not figure out why, any pointers?

Comment: `CsvHelper` is a free Library. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001377/best-way-to-add-nuget-packages-as-project-references-in-vs2012

Comment: Thank you, How do I add this to my project. Once again I am sorry to be a pain and I am truly grateful.

Comment: You could google this.. R-Click Reference -> NuGet -> Search for CsvHelper.